# What is the convention to name a (case) class with long parameter values?

Tags: scala, conventions

If I have a `class` or `case class` whose parameters are long enough to not fit in a single line like:

```
case class Foo(foo1: String, foo2: String, foo3: Int, foo4: Char, foo5: Long, foo6: Double, foo7: Array[Int])
```

To improve readability, how should it be splitted into several lines? Is there a convention for this in **Scala**?

Comment: I put each on its own line. This makes it easy to see what changed in a diff.

Comment: Use Scala style guide to learn about style conventions, in particular this page http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations to learn about class declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the auto-formatters in Scala that I've seen, if you break it into multiple lines at all the formatter will do this:

```
case class Foo(
  foo1: String, 
  foo2: String, 
  foo3: Int, 
  foo4: Char, 
  foo5: Long, 
  foo6: Double, 
  foo7: Array[Int]
)
```

You may also want to consider if any of those parameters can be grouped into a case class of their own though, reducing the number of parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the consideration, I posted this answer because I was using __IntellJ IDEA__ and it was formatted aligned to `Foo(` and not indented two the left as your answer. In the Scala Style Guide shared by @yuriy-gatilin in a comment says that for classes it should better be a four space indentation instead of two.